# Typo3 - How to get the extbase context within a symfony commandController

Tags: symfony, typo3, scheduler

Since TYPO3 v9.4 the extbase commandController is deprecated so I use the symfony console command replacement according to: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html#cli-mode

Now my FooCommandController extends from Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command

Since I need to work with TYPO3 data I need to get them via the extbase repositories.
But my whole CommandController does not have the extbase context so loading the repo via extbase dependency injection is not possible.

Also creating them manually via makeInstance or objectManager->get() is not possible since there is no objectManager available in this context.

What is the correct/non-hacky way to get access to the extbase functionallity inside a symfony commandController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "easiest" but not recommend way would be to fetch `ObjectManager` via `makeInstance()` and use `get()` on it.

A better way would be to separate your logic in a custom class, which uses the Dependency Injection of Extbase. You can then fetch this class the same way.

With V10 you would be able to just inject, as DI is available outside of Extbase.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right path already. You just need an ObjectManager instance:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
...

$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$repo = objectManager->get(FooRepository::class);
```

From TYPO3 v10 we can use Symfony dependency injection (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html).

Comment: OK, but this does not tell the Repository where to store new records for example. This configuration (which comes from the Typoscript Setup) is missing. 
What is the easiest / most compliant way to overcome this?

Comment: It will, if the configuration is available. Extbase will use the BackendConfigurationManager to fetch the TypoScript. StoragePid needs to be set on module.tx_* path properly and needs to be available on the expected page.

Though it is not the nicest way.